# Invalid object name dbo.Categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC 3. I am trying to create Simliar application as MVC Music Store         but I am getting an error. My code is below:

```
 using EFCodeFirst
 BookDBContext _db = new BookDBContext();
 [ChildActionOnly]
 public ActionResult GenreMenu()
 {
    var categories = _db.Category.ToList();//**Giving error at this pointInvalid object name dbo.Categories**
        return PartialView(categories);
 }
```

Comment: Please consider adding more context to your question. I've edited it for formatting and cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your `BookDBContext` contains a property called `Category` and that your database contains table `dbo.Categories`.