# Why am I getting this "Invalid object name 'dbo.*'" error with MVC4?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I get this error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.ImageMetas'.

On this line:

> return View(db.Images.ToList());

Where my database context looks like this:

```
public class GalleryContext : DbContext
{
    public GalleryContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ImageMeta> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageFile> ImageFiles { get; set; }
}
```

And my model:

```
public class ImageMeta
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageFile> Files { get; set; } 
}
```

It's a brand new MVC4 project. I wrote the models first, then auto-generated the controller.

I [inspected the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5310619/65387), and indeed the table is missing.

I was under the impression that it would auto-create the table for me though; as [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) suggests.

So why isn't it doing that?

---

Okay, if I add a connection string named after my context (and remove the base constructor), it works now. Why can't I use the DefaultConnection, then?

```
<add name="GalleryContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\gallery.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Comment: have you created your db by hand? Do you have a connection string in your config named "DefaultConnection"? Can you post your connection strings?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting non-existing database in connection string. EF Code-First will create database if it does not exist by default (of course, if credentials provided have rights to create database), but it will not change existing database (because it may affect your existing data).

Changes to existing database are meant to be done using [code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621).

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, if you don't care about data at all, you can set database initializer (i.e. in global.asax application start) which drops and recreates database every time you change your model:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>());
```

See [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I read a bit about migrations, but I don't want to go through that hassle just yet; I'm still speccing everything out and I'm not worried about losing data. So you're saying I'm getting this exception because it won't modify the DefaultConnection database? Not even to add brand new tables, which shouldn't affect anything else?

Comment: No, EF is not that smart to make a difference between "breaking" and "non-breaking" changes to database, but if you don't care about data, you can set dropcreate initializer, I'm updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem and found a solution, which requires that the User Schema in SQL is that of the dbo schema thus the tables are created with dbo. at the beginning of them, problem solved.

I am presuming this is a bug that will need fixed by MS.

Comment: In earlier versions of the Entity Framework, yes. In EF 6.1, you can actually add a class/model for a new view/table without having to regenerate everything in that project.  You can do it in a side project, then copy/paste it in, and update your main DB model with the name of the DbSet using the existing entries as examples - just name it with a class and name that corresponds to the new table/view in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue while using Database first approach. Connection string in my service's/service's host web.config was incorrect. I corrected the connection string and it worked.