# Why is MVC creating all these new Profiles?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Every time I upload a new image and link it with a Profile, it also creates a new Profile in the wrong database.

I imagine it's created via this code:

```
var imageMeta = new ImageMeta
    {
        Name = imageForm.Name,
        User = Profile,
    };
...
db.Images.Add(imageMeta);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Where `Profile` comes from my `BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private UsersContext _udb = new UsersContext();
    private UserProfile _profile = null;

    public new UserProfile Profile
    {
        get
        {
            if(_profile == null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _profile = _udb.UserProfiles.Single(p => p.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            }
            return _profile;
        }
    }
}
```

That method, `Profile.get`, pulls the correct Profile for the logged-in user from the `UsersContext`, but the `db` in the first snippet is actually a `GalleryContext`.

I'm guessing it doesn't see a profile in that database/context, so it's creating the table and inserting new records into it? Can I tell it not to do that? The users and images are simply stored in two different databases.

I wouldn't mind putting them in the same database, but it [doesn't seem to like using the DefaultContext for my images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12239707/65387).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ImageMeta` and `UserProfile` belong to two separate databases, you have few options.

Instead of having a `UserProfile` type `User` property in `ImageMeta` class, you can provide a scalar property `UserId`.

```
public class ImageMeta
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageFile> Files { get; set; } 
}
```

Then the `ImageMeta` insertion looks like

```
var imageMeta = new ImageMeta
    {
        Name = imageForm.Name,
        UserId = Profile.Id,
    };
...
db.Images.Add(imageMeta);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You can create a materialized view of `UserProfile` on  `GalleryContext` database. Then both contexts will use the same table. After that you can detach the `Profile` instance from `UsersContext` and attach it to `GalleryContext` when saving `ImageMeta`.

Comment: Switching it to `UserId` takes away quite a bit of convenience -- then I have to manually do all the fetching, don't I? I guess I would have to regardless, because it wouldn't be able to handle a cross-database join anyway? What do you mean by "You can create a materialized view of UserProfile on GalleryContext database"?

Comment: @Mark Single `DbContext` can work with only one database. You mentioned that two tables are in different databases. So inorder use these in a single context (ie. joining, navigational properies, etc) you can create a view of `Profile` table in the `GalleryContext` database.

Comment: They were separate `DbContexts` too though.. `UserContext` and `GalleryContext`, as mentioned in the question. I'm not sure what you mean by "create a view" either, I guess I'm not that familiar with MS SQL, but regardless, I've managed to get everything into one database, with only one `DbContext`, and the same issue occurs. It's still creating additional profiles. I could see why it would do that if `Profile.UserId` was `0` or `null`, but it's set properly, so why is it trying to create more instead of just linking it?

Comment: @Mark That maybe because you are using two instances of your context. One to retrieve the `Profile` another one to save `ImageMeta`. A context instance keep track of entities it has loaded. If an entity instance is not found in that tracked list, the context will detect it as a new entity.

Comment: Hrm..well that's a problem. I imagine it's not uncommon for multiple Controllers to use the same DbContext, so how do people get around this? Edit: Actually I can get around this by making `_udb` protected instead and stop re-constructing it in the derived controllers.

Comment: @Mark Use a DI/IoC framework to inject the `DbContext` and configure the lifetime of it to span the request.